# '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command (when running npm install for firebaseUI)

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, npm, npm-install

I cannot install npm packages on my firebaseUI demo application.
I cloned the master branch on github and am simply trying to run "npm install" but I am getting an error I have never come across with node package manager. I get

```
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I also tried this will cygwin64 and had the exact same result. below is the error, and below that is my package.json

```
firebaseui@3.3.0 generate-test-files C:\repos\Firebase Demos\firebaseui-web
> ./buildtools/generate_test_files.sh

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! firebaseui@3.3.0 generate-test-files: `./buildtools/generate_test_files.sh`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the firebaseui@3.3.0 generate-test-files script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\adam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-18T01_43_27_526Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! firebaseui@3.3.0 test: `npm run build && npm run generate-test-files && ./buildtools/run_tests.sh`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the firebaseui@3.3.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\adam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-18T01_43_27_547Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! firebaseui@3.3.0 prepublish: `npm run test && cp -r dist demo/public`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the firebaseui@3.3.0 prepublish script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\adam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-18T01_43_27_577Z-debug.log
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "firebaseui",
  "version": "3.3.0",
  "description": "Javascript library for customizable UI on top of Firebase SDK",
  "files": [
    "dist/firebaseui.js",
    "dist/firebaseui.css",
    "dist/npm.js",
    "dist/index.d.ts",
    "dist/externs",
    "LICENSE",
    "README.md",
    "package.json"
  ],
  "main": "./dist/npm.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "style": "dist/firebaseui.css",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp",
    "build-all": "gulp build-all",
    "build-soy": "gulp build-soy",
    "demo": "npm run build && ./buildtools/run_demo.sh",
    "test": "npm run build && npm run generate-test-files && ./buildtools/run_tests.sh",
    "serve": "npm run build && npm run generate-test-files && gulp serve",
    "generate-test-files": "./buildtools/generate_test_files.sh",
    "prepublish": "npm run test && cp -r dist demo/public"
  },
  "test": "npm run test",
  "author": "Google",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web.git"
  },
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "closure-builder": "^2.2.34",
    "firebase": "^5.0.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^4.0.1",
    "fs-extra": "^3.0.1",
    "google-closure-compiler": "^20171112.0.0",
    "google-closure-library": "^20171112.0.0",
    "google-closure-templates": "^20150410.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.12",
    "gulp-closure-compiler": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-concat-css": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-connect": "^5.5.0",
    "gulp-css-flip": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-css-inline-images": "^0.1.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "material-design-lite": "^1.2.0",
    "protractor": "^5.3.2",
    "streamqueue": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dialog-polyfill": "^0.4.7"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "firebase": ">=5.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is old I ran into the same problem when I was collaborating with another developer using another OS (Linux x Windows).
At the beginning of the project a script `.sh` was failing depending on the OS. We had to constantly modify the `json` file after merging some branch.
The solution we came up with was to append the shell being used to call the script, e.g. we changed the initialization script to

```
...
{
start: bash ./myscript && npm run start
}
...
```

It works fine on Linux and on Gitbash on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

`> ./buildtools/generate_test_files.sh`

here just leave out dot-slash(`./`)

Though, if you wanted to, you could use `.\\` (since single '\' would skip the next character) and it would work.

Comment: Do you know why the ./ is causing such problems. The suggestions you gave did not work, unfortunately